# hazy artefact on OS X WebGL on sides of volume rendering

Tags: macos, glsl, webgl, shader, volume-rendering

Does anyone know how to sort this weird effect? The sides of the volume we're trying to render seem artificially hazy. I'm running it on 2014 MacBook Pro, Intel Iris 1536 MB GPU, Yosemite v 10.10.2 (14C1514). I've heard that this is only a problem on machines running OS X, and it doesn't appear on Windows machines.

[image]

I've also noticed it in some other places e.g. [Leberba](http://www.lebarba.com/WebGL/Index.html)

[image]

Comment: The leberba demo looks exactly the same on my Linux box with an NVidia card and proprietary nvidia driver. What exactly do  you mean by hazy?

Comment: Hi  - thanks for replying. That's interesting it looks the same. By hazy i mean this. in the leberba example - the major front face looks ok (bar some  aliasing effects - something else I want to sort) but the left and top faces, which you are viewing more side on, are artificially green.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1337

Comment: I think we've cornered this behaviour now. All artefacts (hazy sides, concentric rings, and separately visible layers) disappear when we switch from interpolation to nearest neighbour sampling i.e. by adding this line 

texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;

to our THREE.js code.


Incidentally, this drastically slows down the rendering, which we found very surprising. Isn't the shader doing far fewer texture lookups now?

Comment: it seems that the artefacts are caused by the mip mapping in the texture lookup. Anyone know why this might be OS dependent? Or how to sort it? we'd like to keep using mip mapping.

Answer (score 0):

khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1337

Bug reported so closing